# How to access a helper method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a rails app with a `main_controller` for providing content to the main page of my app.  I want to access a collection of images so I created the following method in the controller:

```
def featured_illustrations
    #future implementation: get images where featred == true
    @featured_illustrations << Illustration.find(152)
    @featured_illustrations << Illustration.find(272)
    @featured_illustrations << Illustration.find(275)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @featured_illustrations }
    end
  end
helper_method :featured_illustrations
```

I have the following helper:

```
module MainHelper
  require MainController
  @featured_illustrations = MainController.featured_illustrations
end
```

And the following code in the `featured_images` partial:

```
<div class="featured">
  <% @featured_illustrations.each do |illustration| %>  
   <!-- somc code to print images -->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I get this error when I try to view the page:

```
uninitialized constant MainHelper::MainController
```

I haven't worked with helpers before so any guidance is appreciated.  Thanks.

UPDATE:
I've removed the `MainHelper` but now I'm getting the following error when I try to load the page:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <div class="featured">
2:   <% featured_illustrations.each do |illustration| %>  
3:     <div class="feature-image" id="feature-one">152</div>
4:     <div class="feature-image" id="feature-two">272</div>
5:     <div class="feature-image" id="feature-three">275</div>
```

Any thoughts on the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: In the error you posted, it looks like you're not iterating over the correct variable. You've assigned your featured illustrations to an instance variable (they start with @) not a local variable which is what you're using.

Change:

```
<% featured_illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
```

To:

```
<% @featured_illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
```

However, I'm not exactly sure why you need a helper here if all you're doing is setting an instance variable to access in the partial.

In your `featured_illustrations` you're setting the instance variable. I'm not sure what action you're using when rendering your partial given the name is `featured_images` though.

I would suggest:

app/controllers/main_controller.rb

```
def featured_illustrations
  @featured_illustrations = Illustration.where(featured: true)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @featured_illustrations }
  end
end
```

app/views/main/featured_illustrations.html.erb

```
<div class="featured">
  <% @featured_illustrations.each do |illustration| %>  
    <!-- somc code to print images -->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is assuming that you have your routes file setup to correctly route to the main controller for the featured illustrations method. Something like:

```
match '/featured_illustrations/', to: 'main#featured_illustrations'
```

Finally, you might want to look at how Rails uses REST and resourceful routing in case you haven't already done so. You can find a lot in the [Getting Started with Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: while your method is no longer causing an error, I cannot get the partial to appear even if I clear out the ruby code portion.  this is how I'm calling the parital:  `<%= render :partial => "main/featured_illustrations", :collection => @featured_illustrations %>`

Comment: The snippet you've got there is ERB which means that you're rendering another template first and then passing the `@featured_illustrations` as a collection object to the `featured_illustrations` partial. What file is that snippet in? Also, partials are named with underscores in front. You would need to rename the `app/views/main/featured_illustrations.html.erb` to `app/views/main/_featured_illustrations.html.erb` for the renderer to pick it up.